# Python Access Selenium Webdriver Instance from another Process

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

I am writing a code, which opens a Chrome selenium webdriver (`driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(exec = chromedriver_path)`) instance in a new process and I want to access that driver instance from the main process. I tried using a global queue `qu = queue.Queue`, but when I try to insert the driver into the queue (`qu.put(driver)`) it gives me this error : `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.encodekey'`, which means the data is not pickable. What is the best way to access the driver instance from another process? Is this even possible?